# Deleting my account only for one site and not for all sites

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

Previously I asked to delete only my Meta account, but my Stack Overflow account was deleted as well. How can I prevent this in the future?

Comment: Don't copy the "please delete me" to all accounts.

Comment: You can also have better luck by not impersonating other users. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you only write "please delete me" in the profile box for the site you wish to be deleted in only.  Save it to that profile only.